# What am I missing in this Perl search string to make it match?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large file that is full of text lines that I want to parse out specific data from. A sample line of the data I want is:

```
results:    IF-MIB::ifInOctets.9 = Counter32: 23212027
```

where the value of Counter32 changes and the if*.Octets.\d changes. I don't mind needing multiple 'if' statements to get the data if needed, but I have been unable to determine what i'm missing. i've checked perl reference docs and regex help docs and am unable to see what I am missing.

here is a sample of what i have (the base form of which works in other projects i am working on):

```
my $line = $_;
#print $line;
if ($line =~ "/result.*ifOutOctets\.6.* = counter32/i"){
print $line; #this is here only for testing to see if I am matching the line since the file is not filling in
```

I have tried using the following lines in the if($line =~"") location and I am sure i am missing something simple but can't find what it is:

```
/result(.*)ifOut(.*) = counter32/i
/result.*ifOut.* = counter32: (\d*)/i
/result.*IF-MIB::ifOut.*(\d*) = counter32: (\d*)/i
```

I have a Mac here that I used for testing via grep and it is returning results successfully using this form:

```
grep -i "result.*ifOutOctets.* = counter32" fileName
```

Comment: I think @Andrew has it, but I notice your sample contains `ifInOctets` and your pattern has `ifOutOctets`. Is this a cut & paste error?

Comment: Also, the suffix is .9 in the input, and .6 in the search expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl you don't quote the regex. Corrected code is:

```
my $line = $_;
if ($line =~ /result.*ifOutOctets\.6.* = counter32/i)
{
    # do whatever
}
```

Comment: Andrew's answer I believe is what you need, but for sake of expanding it to get what you are looking for, I believe you will want:  `if ($line =~ /^result.*?ifOutOctets\.(\d+) = counter32: (\d+)/i)`

Comment: Thanks, Andrew!
That worked; sorry I missed that from my checking. Justin Morgan and beny23, thank you for catching my typos in my sample data. I will try to fix that in my original post (if not, yes, it was a copy/paste/read-from-wrong-spot mistake that i thought i had checked to make sure wasn't there).